# How do you cancel a workflow on a record using SuiteScript?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

The UI has a clear option to cancel a workflow on a record (such as a transaction).

Is there a way to do that programmatically using SuiteScript (2.0)?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a workflow instance programmatically so it's not possible to cancel a workflow.